# Instanciar uma classe com atributos privados

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, herança, encapsulamento

Como eu consigo pegar os atributos da classe pessoa e instanciar elas na classe médico para depois exibi-la? O médico e o paciente são pessoas e ambos possuem os atributos da classe `Pessoa`. Deixei alguns atributos como privados pois são dados sensíveis.

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome, rg, cpf, telefone):
        self.nome = nome
        self.__rg = rg
        self.__cpf = cpf
        self.telefone = telefone

    def get_cpf(self):
        return self.__cpf

    def set_cpf(self, cpf):
        self.__cpf = cpf
        return self.__cpf

    def get_rg(self):
        return self.__rg

    def set_rg(self, rg):
        self.__rg = rg
        return self.__rg

    def exibir_dados():


class Medico(Pessoa):
    def __init__(self, nome, rg, cpf, telefone, crm, salario, especialidade):
        super().__init__(nome, rg, cpf, telefone)
        self.crm = crm
        self.salario = salario
        self.especialidade = especialidade

    def dados_medico(self):
        super().exibir_dados()
        print('Telefone: ', self.telefone)
        print('CRM: ', self.crm)
        print('Salário: ', self.salario)
        print('Especialidade: ', self.especialidade)


class Paciente(Pessoa):
    def __init__(self, nome, rg, cpf, telefone, endereco, nascimento):
        super().__init__(nome, rg, cpf, telefone)
        self.endereco = endereco
        self.nascimento = nascimento

medico_01 = Medico('Fulano de Tal', 12345647, 99933366645,
                   1199553644, '1111/SP', 2500.50, 'Ortopedista')
medico_01.dados_medico()
```

Comment: Resolveu sim, estive estudando sobre atributos privados e como acessá-los de outra classe.  Muito obrigado,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O maior motivo de não funcionar é que o método de exibição não tem um parâmetro para receber o objeto, no caso o `self` como usou nos demais métodos.

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome, rg, cpf, telefone):
        self.nome = nome
        self.__rg = rg
        self.__cpf = cpf
        self.telefone = telefone
    
    def get_cpf(self):
        return self.__cpf
    
    def set_cpf(self, cpf):
        self.__cpf = cpf
        return self.__cpf
    
    def get_rg(self):
        return self.__rg
    
    def set_rg(self, rg):
        self.__rg = rg
        return self.__rg
    
    def exibir_dados(self):
        pass

class Medico(Pessoa):
    def __init__(self, nome, rg, cpf, telefone, crm, salario, especialidade):
        super().__init__(nome, rg, cpf, telefone)
        self.crm = crm
        self.salario = salario
        self.especialidade = especialidade
    
    def dados_medico(self):
        super().exibir_dados()
        print('Telefone: ', self.telefone)
        print('CRM: ', self.crm)
        print('Salário: ', self.salario)
        print('Especialidade: ', self.especialidade)

class Paciente(Pessoa):
    def __init__(self, nome, rg, cpf, telefone, endereco, nascimento):
        super().__init__(nome, rg, cpf, telefone)
        self.endereco = endereco
        self.nascimento = nascimento

medico_01 = Medico('Fulano de Tal', 12345647, 99933366645, 1199553644, '1111/SP', 2500.50, 'Ortopedista')
medico_01.dados_medico()
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/82UfVp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/msborvtn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/SelfParameter.py).

Mas não entendi o que ter campos privados tem a ver com dados serem sensíveis. Por acaso acredita que está criando algum proteção de dados fazendo isso? Se for isso, reveja completamente sua ideia sobre segurança. Também ter campos privados não é encapsulamento, procure bons materiais sobre o assunto, aqui no site tem.

Parece ter erros conceituais no código, mas não posso afirmar sem entender completamente o problema.